# Image Processing App for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, opencv, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, emgucv

I want to write an Image Processing App for **Windows Phone** in any of the below framework:

- *Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 Silverlight
- Windows Phone 8.1 (Runtime)
- Windows Universal 8.1*

Languages I know are **C#** and **XAML**

I downloaded OpenCv,EmguCv but all are in C++. Now I got OpenCV for WindowsUniversal but its in c++. Then I got OpenCV for windows in C# but it has forms and cannot be used to write Windows Store App.

I am confused like hell. From where to start. Kindly guide.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a version of opencv that works with uwp apps

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2015/12/04/opencv-first-version-up-on-nuget.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2015/11/28/opencv-building-uwp-binaries.aspx

You can also use the lumia imaging sdk with any UWP app

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt598502.aspx

Comment: The problem is, its all in C++ but I am a C# Developer

Comment: the lumia imaging sdk works under c#